# JS how do i make a <main> element focused on when the page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<main id="news">...Content...</main>` and I am trying to make it focused on when the document is loaded for scrollbar purposes since the rest of the page fits on the whole page and does not go past that point so any content that is longer is in the news div and I want to make sure that if a user wishes to use the arrow key to scroll down that they don't have to click on the element first (just a nifty feature I'd like to add)

Comment: did you try my solution? I wonder if it could work

Comment: I did try and nothing sorry. I'm not sure why it doesn't work because I understand the theory and it makes sense that it should work

Comment: problem with loading jQuery then, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Try once, Just a hack, add this before closing the body tag,

```
<script>
$(function(){
   $('#news').click();
});
</script>
```

I'm trying to click the news section after the page has loaded, so that the focus is on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a limited set of elements that can receive actual “focus” *by default* (mainly “interactive” elements, such as links and form elements).

Other elements you have to make “focus-able” first, by using the [`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) attribute.

```
<main tabindex="0">…
```

Now this element can actually receive focus, so that you can use the `focus` method to make it do that:

```
var main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
main.focus();
```

See this fiddle: <del>http://jsfiddle.net/Legs545x/</del> http://jsfiddle.net/Legs545x/2/ (Added `display:block` for `main` here for the benefit of Internet Explorer, which doesn’t do that by default, so that setting the `height` wasn’t working otherwise.)

This works in current Chrome and IE 11; in Firefox it doesn’t work within the jsfiddle environment – in the full screen view however it does, https://jsfiddle.net/Legs545x/2/embedded/result/

In all those browsers you should see the `main` element get a red-ish background once the fiddle has loaded (via `main:focus { background:#f99; }`), and you should be able to scroll within it using the up and down arrow keys or page up/page down, without having to click into it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#news').focus();

});
```

Comment: that didn't give me any result at all as did nothing else I've tried

Comment: I think that maybe my question was not clear enough my entire site fits on the screen and my `<main>` element is the only one with a scrollbar and I want to set it so that when the page loads the user doesn't have to click on the element to be able to scroll with the arrow keys the body doesn't have a scrollbar at all

Comment: Still nothing and it's kind of annoying that my browser doesn't return jquery errors

Comment: how do I check for that??

Comment: You may want to add in your answer, at least, a little explanation on how and why this code snippet does answer the OP question, as an for the OP as well as for any future reader of you answer having the same issue.

Comment: it's not returning anything but i tried a different jquery function and that worked so I have no Idea whats going on